# Is this integral bounded for every value of epsilon

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Working on my thesis I need to prove or disprove that there exists $1/2 < \alpha <1$ and $C$ independent of $\epsilon \in (0,1]$

$$\int_0^s \int_r^s \frac{1}{\epsilon} (s-r)^{-\alpha}(s-\tau)^{-\alpha}e^{-\lambda (s-r)}e^{-\lambda (s-\tau)}e^{-\delta (\tau-r)/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}\tau\,\mathrm{d}r < C$$
where $s,r \in [0,T]$, $T, \lambda>0, \delta>0$ are fixed and $1>\epsilon >0$ is a parameter.

Then by Holder with $3/2, 3$ coniugates

$$\leq \left [\int_0^{s} \int_r^{s}  (s-\tau)^{-3/2\alpha}(s-r)^{-3/2\alpha}e^{-3/2\lambda (s-\tau)}e^{-3/2\lambda (s-r)} dz  d\nu\right ]^{2/3} \\ \times \left [\int_0^{s} \int_r^{s}  e^{-3\delta (\tau-r)/\epsilon} \frac{1}{\epsilon^3}\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}\nu \right]^{1/3}.
$$
Now the first integral is finite and independent of $\epsilon$ if $1/2 < \alpha < 2/3$. But the second integral seems to depend on $\epsilon$. (I can't use Holder wit $p=2$ since I have $\alpha> 1/2$). Do you see other ways or the claim is wrong?

Comment: Well, you can remove the $\frac1{\epsilon}$ part, because it is just noise - it doesn’t affect finiteness.

Comment: Yes of course but I need a uniform bound wrt $\epsilon$

Comment: Not sure how that affects this question. All you ask for here is finiteness. You can certainly just take $\frac1{\epsilon}$ out of the integral, since it is constant.

Comment: No the point is that $\epsilon$ will eventually go to zero. For this  I dont need just finateness for every epsilon but a uniform bound

Comment: But your question doesn’t ask about a uniform bound. And you can still do: $$\iint \frac1{ \epsilon} \dots=\frac1{\epsilon}\iint\dots$$ and not have $\frac1{\epsilon^3}$ in your use of Holder.

Comment: But I ask that $C$ is independent of $\epsilon$ if I do like you suggest I end up with $C/\epsilon$ which depends on epsilon.

Comment: So you aren’t looking for finiteness (in the title) but whether it is bounded. Bounded is much stronger, and should be in the title. And you can still take the fraction out of the integral.

Comment: Yes sorry the title is wrong

Comment: I Corrected the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true. We have

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_0^s\int_r^s(s-r)^{-a}(s-\tau)^{-a}e^{-\lambda(s-r)}e^{-\lambda(s-\tau)} e^{-\delta(\tau-r)/\varepsilon}d\tau dr\\
\ge &\frac{e^{-2\lambda s}}{\varepsilon} \int_{0}^s (s-r)^{-2a} \int_{r}^s e^{-\delta(\tau-r)/\varepsilon}= \frac{1}{\delta}\int_0^s (s-r)^{-2a}(1-e^{-\delta(s-r)/\varepsilon})dr\\
\ge &\frac{1}{\delta} \int_{s-\varepsilon}^s(s-r)^{-2a}(1-e^{-\delta(s-r)/\varepsilon})dr\ge \frac{\varepsilon^{-2a}}{\delta}\int_{s-\varepsilon}^s(1-e^{-\delta(s-r)/\varepsilon})dr\\
=&\frac{\varepsilon^{-2a}}{\delta}(\varepsilon-\frac{\varepsilon}{\delta}+\frac{\varepsilon}{\delta}e^{-\delta})=\frac{\varepsilon^{1-2a}}{\delta}(1-1/\delta+e^{-\delta}/\delta)\to\infty
\end{align*}

as $\delta\to0$, since $a>1/2$ and $1-1/\delta+e^{-\delta}>0$.